# how to print list in Django template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I received a List in this format from PostgreSQL.

```
[(11, 'www.xyz.com', '03216784000', 'THis is admin side vendor', ['2020,2002'], ['Plugs,genrator'], 'zeshan@gmail.com,zeshan@hotmail.com', ['Corolla,toyota'])]

 Here is my Model and I insert data using ajax inpostgresql.
class StaffUser(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer_vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True) 
    emails = MultiEmailField()    
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) 
    category = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), null=True, blank=True)
    menufacture = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), null=True, blank=True)
    buyer_model = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), null=True, blank=True)
```

Using this very simple query

```
vendor_record = StaffUser.objects.get(user_id=id)
```

I try to print or show a list special ['Corolla,Toyota] using split
but could not remove the comma.

I don't know how to print the whole list special ['Corolla,Toyota] type of data. anyone, please help. I am new to
Django and could not find accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the list in the template, you can simply loop over the list and print individual items.

**Example**

```
{%for i in list_name%}
   {{i}}
{%end for%}
```

Or you can also use the Django join template tag

```
{{ list_name|join:"--" }}
```

here is the list is [1, 2, 3, 4] it will print 1--2--3--4

Comment: i used for loop for ['Plugs,genrator'].
then result in Plugs,generator. I need result in new line. not with comma seprater